# Sum column values based on multiple criteria in data table j

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data table data1 (more lines and more variations but this is a sample):

```
    item cat1 cat2 cat3 amounts
 1:    1   99 9999 9990     100
 2:    2   12 8199 9990     100
 3:    3   12 8199 9990     100
 4:    4   12 8199 9990     100
 5:    5   12 8199 9990     100
 6:    6   12 8199 9990     100
 7:    7   12 8199 9990     100
 8:    8   12 4129 9990     100
 9:    9   12 8199 9990     100
10:   10   12 8199 9990     100

library(data.table)
data1 <- setDT(structure(list(item = 1:10, cat1 = c("99", "12", "12", "12", 
"12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12"), cat2 = c("9999", "8199", 
"8199", "8199", "8199", "8199", "8199", "4129", "8199", "8199"
), cat3 = c("9990", "9990", "9990", "9990", "9990", "9990", "9990", 
"9990", "9990", "9990"), amounts = c("100", "100", "100", "100", 
"100", "100", "100", "100", "100", "100")), .Names = c("item", 
"cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "amounts"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L)))
```

Initially I wanted to get some information about the lines that fulfilled some criteria based on cat1, cat2, cat3. And so I did something like this:

```
data1[, .(  items = .N,
            group1 = sum(grepl("^[1-8]{2}$", cat1)),
            group2 = sum(grepl("^[1-8]9$", cat1)),
            group3 = sum(grepl("^9[1-8]$", cat1)),
            group4 = sum(cat1 == "99"))]
```

With the result being:

```
    items group1 group2 group3 group4
1:    10      9      0      0      1
```

There were lots of other criteria included in the analysis but this is also just a sample. My requirements changed and now for every group that is specified I need to sum also the amounts. 
So I have two questions:

1) Is there a way in data table to do this summation in a similar way to the one for calculating the counts (so the basic idea would be something like `sum(amounts)` where `grepl("^[1-8]{2}$", cat1)` )

2) Is there an efficient way of doing this that I am missing? I cannot think of any good way of getting my result aside from adding new columns to the original dataset for each criterion that I have and then doing a filtered sum.

My ideal result would be:

```
    items group1 group2 group3 group4 total_amounts  group1_amounts   group2_amounts group3_amounts group4_amounts
1:    10      9      0      0      1          1000            900              0              0            100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say: make a table for the full mapping to groups (which are mutually exclusive):

```
m = data.table(g = paste0("group", 1:4))[,.(cat1 = as.character(
  if (.GRP==1L) combn(1:8, 2, paste0, collapse = "") else
  if (.GRP==2L) paste0(1:8, 9) else
  if (.GRP==3L) paste0(9, 1:8) else
  if (.GRP==4L) "99"
)), by=g]
```

Verify that the mapping is...

```
stopifnot(m[duplicated(cat1), .N == 0L])   # mutually exclusive
stopifnot(data1[!m, on=.(cat1), .N == 0L]) # exhaustive
```

Add group as a variable to the main table:

```
data1[m, on=.(cat1), g := i.g]
```

Join on groups to summarize by each group:

```
res = data1[.(g = unique(m$g)), on=.(g), .(.N, tot_amt = sum(as.numeric(amounts), na.rm=TRUE)), by=.EACHI]

#         g N tot_amt
# 1: group1 9     900
# 2: group2 0       0
# 3: group3 0       0
# 4: group4 1     100
```

I think this is the more useful format for the output, but if you really want the one-line output...

```
cbind(N = sum(res$N), dcast(res, . ~ g, value.var=c("N","tot_amt")))[, !"."]

#     N N_group1 N_group2 N_group3 N_group4 tot_amt_group1 tot_amt_group2 tot_amt_group3 tot_amt_group4
# 1: 10        9        0        0        1            900              0              0            100
```

---

*How the "join" step works*

The syntax is `x[i, on=cols, j, by=.EACHI]`, where `i` is a list or data.table.

- `.()` is an alias for `list()` inside some arguments of `x[...]`.
- `by=.EACHI` means group by each row of `i` (even for rows of `i` unmatched in `x`).
- As usual, `j` is computed for each group determined in `by=`.

---

*Comments*

When making the group column, I think it's much better to make a table instead of using a series of regexes, like `data1[grepl(yada), g := 1L][grepl(yada2) & is.na(g), g := 2L][grepl(yada3) & is.na(g), g := 3L]` since with the latter, there's no way to catch cases where there is duplicated assignment (`cat1` assigned to multiple `g`) or missed assignment (`cat1` assigned to no `g`).

And when summarizing by group, I think it's best to do `data1[.(all_groups), on=.(g), ..., by=.EACHI]` rather than `data1[, ..., by=g]` since the latter will skip groups that happen to not appear in the table.